# Field value of a content type is not saved

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a content type (created through a feature) which has different fields. One field is a text field. It used to save data before but now it doesn't save any value. I checked in the table, the value is not there. I checked in `hook_node_update` the field is empty. 
I tried to write `hook_field_is_empty` in my module and also in feature but didn't help :(.
W
hat can cause this? Thank you.

Comment: If I create another text field on that content type, it saves data but not that specific field.

Comment: Thank you for downgrading it, any special reason for it?

Comment: I'm speculating, but it's probably because of the very broad nature of the question. There are dozens of things that could be wrong, without more information from you this is near impossible to answer, and as such not a good question for the site. You'll need to do some more advanced debugging and provide more details if you want an answer, otherwise the question will probably wind up closed as "too broad"

Comment: How can we know what happened between "it used to save" and "it doesn't save", if you don't tell us? Also, you have some hooks that may affect your situation, but you didn't show the code. So from downvote button description "no research effort" and "unclear" may fit.

Comment: What else I should do? I tried hook_node_update to see if value is there.  I have to work with someone else's code. I searched for hooks but couldn't find something special that may affect. I will search again.

Comment: At least you can see the code. If you, having access to code and environment, cannot answer this, how can you expect we will, having even less data? See these links: https://www.drupal.org/node/260854 https://www.drupal.org/node/1846954

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check you are accessing the field properly. I'd recommend adding `<pre><?php print_r($node); ?>` in one of your theme tpl files and then accessing it manually like `$node->field_example['und'][0]['value']`. It always helps me.